# How to create a new variable in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, eval, v8, ecmascript-2016

Consider this code

```
'use strict';

var factory = () => script => eval(script);
var closure = factory();

closure('var v = 0');
var val = closure('typeof v');

console.log(val);
```

This is my attempt to achieve it. I want to create a closure and then to allow users to create a new local variable in that closure. Is that even possible?

I somewhere read that *"native function 'eval' can even create a new variable in the local execution context."*. So, why doesn't it work in my example? My guess is that it is because the function finished executin and number of variables after function ends cannot be changed, but I am not sure.

My example script creates a closure and tries to declare and initialize new variable `v` in that closure and assign number `0` to it. I expected that the result of `typeof v` should be `number`, but it is actually `undefined`.

So, I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't it creates the variable `v` as expected
2. How to actually achieve that (what would be the working example)?

Comment: What exactly are you tryin to build here? How about creating an object to store your context and adding properties to this object instead of trying to hack into closures.

Comment: Why do you need this? I have an answer 75% done, but I realized how odd and useless this seems. Why do you need to create new variables inside a scope like this? And note, every time you call `closure`, you're creating a new scope. All the calls to `closure` aren't "connected".

Comment: @Thomas. I know I can use object instead, but I am just asking for this method in order to better understand how javascript works.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. I know it is useless (or at least I couldn't find real world use of it), but I am just trying to understand how javascript works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is locally scoped, but a bit too local

```
var factory = () =>{
  return script =>{
   //this is the scope. you cant access any variables outside of this.
   eval(script);
  };
  //you want to eval here, which is impossible
};
```

You could do very hacky scope stuff to work around this ( store all variables in context):

```
var factory = (context={}) => script =>{ with(context){ return eval(script); }};
```

You need to initialize all local variables on creation:

```
var exec=factory({v:0, b:undefined});// note that you need to set a value explicitly {v,b} wont worm
```

and then it works as expected:

```
console.log(
 exec("v"),//0
 exec("v=2"),//2
 exec("v"),//2
 typeof v //undefined
);
```

http://jsbin.com/xibozurizi/edit?console

---

If you dont want to go that deep, the only thing you could do would be concatenating the strings:

```
var factory =  code => concat => (eval(code),res=eval(concat),code+=concat,res);
// or shorter / more buggy 
var factory =  code => concat => eval(code+=";"+concat);

var exec=factory("var a=1;");
console.log(
 exec("a;"),//1
 exec("var b=a+1"),
 exec("b"),//2
 tyepof a, typeof b //undefined
);
```

http://jsbin.com/midawahobi/edit?console

---

The upper code will run the strings multiple times, which is may not wanted. Another approach:

```
var factory=code=>({
  code,
  run(c){
    return eval(this.code+";"+c);
  },
  add(c){ this.code+=";"+c}
});
```

So you can do

```
var exec=factory("var a='hello'");
exec.run("alert(a)")//alerts hello
exec.add("var b=a+' world'");
console.log(exec.code,exec.run("b"));//hello world, the upper alert isnt run again
```

http://jsbin.com/lihezuwaxo/edit?console

note that evaling is always a bad idea...

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Good explained. However, I don't have enough rep to give +1, sorry.

Comment: @FigliDelleTenebre youre welcome ;) and i think you will be able soon...

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `eval()` *does* create a new variable, and it does so in the local execution context of the call. That context is *inside* that function, so it doesn't effect the context *outside*, where you call `closure()`.

Generally `eval()` is to be strictly avoided. It makes optimization hard (or impossible) so functions that use it will be ignored by the optimizer. There are some rare circumstances in which it's useful, but declaring a new local variable doesn't seem like one of them.

Comment: I know `eval` is not for commercial or serious use, but I am just trying to understand concepts of JavaScript and how it works, nothing more. I know evaling code should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that

```
var factory = () => script => eval(script);
var closure = factory();
var v;
closure('v=20')
```

Comment: But it creates global variable (or at least variable in the parent scope). If you try to create a new closure, it would use the same variable `v`.